# In magento 1.9.1.0 None of the emails are going out

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

forget password,newsletter,wishlist share,scale,order conformation mail 
No one option is not working

system->configuration->Store email address.... i give a all user id

Then enable the all option on top denoted but its can't working

am install SMTP Pro Email - Free Custom SMTP Email->showing this error its not working ,now how to fix that mail communication issues

Comment: Did you check if cron is configured? 1.9.1 started using cron for sending emails.

Comment: corn also  given...till none of mail communication is not working.

Comment: order  confirmation mail  only not working  now , i enable the scale order mail config in magento , and smpt test mail alos working fine ,order related mail only not working ,what the issuse for site plz share me  @razbakov

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that email communications are enable in Configuration->Advanced Tab->System->Mail sending options
2. Then goto SMTP Pro configuration tab, enable below settings in general settings.

   Email Connection->Custom SMTP.
   Authentication->Login.
   Username->mail user
   Password->your password
   Host->your mail host(for gmail gmail.smtp.com)
   Port->by default 25
   SSL->based on your email service
3. Then goto Logging and Debugging section enable log emails to yes, save settings.
4. Now check mail settings by run self test under Logging and Debugging section by click the 'Run self Test' button. If the status will be success the mails were send successfully otherwise need to change the setting.
5. The Store config emails(Sales emails and others too) should be same as username which you give in general setting. This only for customer SMTP

Comment: SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Detected overwrite conflict: Sendinblue_Sendinblue_Model_Email
Detected overwrite conflict: Sendinblue_Sendinblue_Model_Email_Template

Comment: Disable that module(Sendinblue) in System->configuration->Advanced Tab->Advanced.

Comment: I Sendinblue disabled that then clear the cache Showing this message
SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Detected overwrite conflict: Sendinblue_Sendinblue_Model_Email
Detected overwrite conflict: Sendinblue_Sendinblue_Model_Email_Template
Sending test email to your contact form address: itsupports@eshtari.me from: itsupports@eshtari.me.
Test email was sent successfully.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.

Testing failed, please review the reported problems and if you need further help visit the support page or contact me via support@aschroder.com for support.

Comment: Did you see test email in smtp pro log under System->Tools->Smtp pro log

Comment: SMTP test mail is only coming in log bt ,other mail communication is not working  forget-password mail wishlist share mail, order confirmation mail ,registration mail like that mail communication is not working , sample mail add to ftp its working ,in magneto mail communication only not working

Comment: 1) try this extension for email - https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension and this for cron - https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler 2) try deactivate your module changing the file in /app/etc/modules/

Comment: SMTP Pro Self Test Results
Sending test email to your contact form address: itsupport@eshtari.me from: itsupport@eshtari.me. 
Test email was sent successfully.
Default templates exist.
Email communications are enabled.

Testing complete, if you are still experiencing difficulties please visit the support page or contact me via support@aschroder.com for support.      Now also not working any one mail communication ..for example forget password also not working , then install Aoepeole extension if any pblm arising !!..

Answer (score 0):

There 3 possible problems:

- standard mail function doesn't work or not server not configured properly
- cron configured wrong
- you are using the same address of sender and receiver

#### SMTP handler:

You can configure Magento to use SMTP instead of standard mail function:

- install [Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension](http://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension) to handle email sending

Ashley (the extension creator) describes what the advantages are:

> This Magento extension is created for expert users who need full control of the Magetno SMTP server settings. You can control authentication, security and specify your own host and port. The extension supports self testing and Magento newsletters. This extension now also has the ability to easily configure and send from Gmail or Google Apps email addresses.

#### Debugging:

Since Magento CE 1.9.1 is using cron to schedule email sending you might need those extensions for debugging:

- [Aoe_Scheduler](http://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler). AOE Scheduler helps to debug cron. AOE Scheduler sits on top of Magento's default cron functionality allowing you to manage the jobs, to visualize the timeline and to get some deeper insight on what's going on behind the scenes and to shed some light on what might be going wrong. On top of that AOE Scheduler provides some more functionality like a cli and a web service interface, optimizing cron execution on your server and giving you everything you need to implement complex background tasks including for your Magento store.
- [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) CLI tool to debug cronjobs. All “new order emails” are queued. A new defined cronjob core_email_queue_send_all is now processing the queued emails

Run:

```
n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:run core_email_queue_send_all
```

Comment: Invoice mail and shipping conformation mail are working but order conformation only not working , Installed that AOE Scheduler  corn all are enable ..i cant to find the error .. please tell to me How to enable the scales order mail ? Is this majar issuse for me @razbakav

Comment: are you using the same address of sender and receiver?

Comment: Did you set up cron as advised in AOE Scheduler?

Comment: 2015-06-19T07:08:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Email not sent immediately, queued for sending. (aschroder_smtppro.log) this log is find in /var/log How to fixed this one , @razbakov thanks

Comment: follow this instructions to set up your cronjob - https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/master/doc/instructions.md